# style attribute not working in writeHTML method of tcpdf class

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdi

Is it possible to add style attribute to html tag when writing to a pdf file using TCPDF's writeHTML method?  Here is sample code:

```
$html = "<div style=\"font-size: 20px; border: solid blue; float: left; margin: 10px 25px 25px 100px;">PRINT</div>";

$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->setSourceFile("some_file_path");
$tmpl = $pdf->ImportPage(1);
$pdf->AddPage('P');
$pdf->writeHTML($html,true,false,false,false,'');
$pdf->Output();
```

I don't see the border or margins working.

Comment: I think your **quotes** is not right

Comment: tpdf's HTML support is 'flaky' there's no real way to map HTML to a pdf so it does its best. Some htlm\css is simply not supported other will not work as expected. The only way i fond to write the html\css is pure experimentation and accept somethings will never work as desired. reading through the source will aslo give you an idea what works and what wont.

Comment: Ya, thats what I figured too.  Also is there a way to add the script tag or that's not supported either?

Comment: adding script makes little sense to me - what specifically did you want to happen ?

Comment: I want to add a print button to the pdf output, so when they click the button it prints the page(pdf)

Comment: in theory: $pdf->IncludeJS($js);  http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_053.phps, http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $html = '<div style="font-size: 20px; border: solid blue; float: left; margin: 10px 25px 25px 100px;">PRINT</div>';

 $pdf = new FPDI();
 $pdf->setSourceFile("some_file_path");
 $tmpl = $pdf->ImportPage(1);
 $pdf->AddPage('P');
 $pdf->writeHTML($html,0);
 $pdf->Output();
```

Comment: ya i copied that $html value over mine's and still didn't see new results.

Comment: Did you write `$pdf->Output();`?

Comment: Maybe your parameters. Is affecting them.

Comment: What if you remove all the false parameters?

Comment: Did you try `$pdf->Write($html, 0);`?